# Adding to database via mysql query - form elements not adding to database

Tags: php, mysql

morning all - amended question, as data now enters db correctly,

I'm a newbie to php/mysql, but through various articles and guides have built a form, which when submitted I want the user to be sent to a separate THANK YOU PAGE (so I can track conversions etc).

Here's the code I'm currently using, which when the form is submitted with no errors, delivers a 'THANK YOU' message on the same page:

```
   <?php
if(isset($error))
    {echo "<span id='Warning'>Please enter all areas marked with *</span>";}
else if (isset($sent))
    {echo "<span id='Normal'>Thank you for your enquiry, we will contact you shortly</span>";}
?>
```

Previously I was using the following after the mysql query (where the fields enter the db), but this sent users to the 'THANK YOU' page even if there were errors with the form they completed

```
header('Location: http://www.THANK-YOU-PAGE');
}
?>
```

Can anyone see anything glaringly wrong? I'm new to this, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) send regards!

Comment: Are you getting any MySql errors?

Comment: Please consider using bind variables to help prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are missing some fields values in the *INSERT INTO* statement. If you don't specify the fields, you have to enter exactly one value for each field, or mysql won't know which value goes in wich field.
So to avoid this, try to write your statement like the following, with the fields you want to populate written in the statement.:

```
INSERT INTO field1, field2 VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
```

Anyway, your query is very insecure. You should use at least [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape user input. You can read about SQL injections in the same link or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). There are other alternatives that I prefer, like using [PDO class of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Thanks one - I removed the

    header('Location: http://www.THANK-YOU-PAGE');
}
  from just after the my sql query and data now appears in the correct fields in the database. So I guess I don't need to do as you suggested, however, how do I know make it so when someone submits the form, they're redirected to a THANK YOU page? At present the following is used:

    <?php
 if(isset($error))
  {echo "<span id='Warning'>Please enter all areas marked with *</span>";}
 else if (isset($sent))
  {echo "<span id='Normal'>Thank you for your enquiry, we will contact you shortly</span>";}
 ?>

Comment: You could do it with javascript, or check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614241/redirect-after-post

Comment: You cannot redirect using `header()` after sending any HTML data.